# Attribute-based authorization in DotNetCore API

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I am converting `.NET` APIs code to `.NET Core` APIs. There are a few APIs that have attribute authorization in the older system. As I understand, `.NET Core` doesn't have attribute authorization. So, how can I accomplish the same?

I'll also give an example of the attribute from the older system below:

```
[RequiredPermission("100,101,102")]
```

I have been reading about `policy-based` authorization hoping to accomplish what the older system did. Basically, I would like to pass in a list of allowed permissions to an API controller action.  Every call would get evaluated against that list to see if the user has those permissions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be compatible with the older system, you can create a simple Authorization `Filter` :

```
public class RequiredPermissionAttribute : Attribute, IAsyncAuthorizationFilter{

    public RequiredPermissionAttribute(string permissions)
    {
        this.Permissions = string.IsNullOrEmpty(permissions) ?
            new List<string>():
            permissions.Split(",").Select(p =>p.Trim()).ToList();
    }

    public IList<string> Permissions {get;set;}

    public async Task OnAuthorizationAsync(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
    {
        var user = context.HttpContext.User;

        var authZService = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<IAuthorizationService>();
        var accessable = await authZService.AuthorizeAsync(user,this.Permissions,"Require Permissions Policy");
        if(!accessable.Succeeded){
            context.Result =  new ForbidResult();
        }
    }
}
```

and now you can use the authorization filter to intercept request :

```
[RequiredPermission("101,102,103")]
public IActionResult Contact()
{
    ViewData["Message"] = "Your contact page.";

    return View();
}
```

Of course , we need to register the policy firstly . :

```
services.AddAuthorization( o=> {
    o.AddPolicy("Require Permissions Policy", pb =>{
        pb.RequireAssertion(async context =>{
            var user = context.User;
            var permissions=context.Resource as IList<string>;
            if(permissions == null || permissions.Count()==0 ){ return true; }
            if(user.Claims.Any( c => c.Type=="MyCustomClaimType" && permissions.Any(p => p.Equals(c.Value)) ))
            {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        });
    });
});
```

For a testing purpose, I just add a simple function to check the policy, you can custom the authorization process as you like.

Comment: Nice. Is that the recommended way of authorizing? I want to make sure I don't stray too far from what's recommended.

Comment: @Skadoosh Typically, it is suggested that we should configure a policy and use the `[Authorize]` to deal with authorization if possible.  But the built-in `AuthorizeAttribute` have no way to pass the permissions to the authorization handler. As it is not recommend to custom our own `[AuthorizeAttribute]` , one approach is to configure your own policy provider, but that is not elegant for your question. Another way is to introduce an `AuthorizeFilter` . I don't know whether there're any other good ways to do that. But as for your question, the filter makes sense here.